# Get non sorted column levels in pandas dataframe with multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background:**

I have a pandas dataframe with MultiIndex.

I want to get the columns.levels NOT sorted.

df.column.levels gives them to me but sorted.

**Example:**

```
worms=['worm1', 'worm2', 'worm3']
bodyparts=['head', 'vulva', 'tail']
coords=['x', 'y']
arrays=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([worms, bodyparts, coords],

                           names=['worms', 'bodyparts', 'coords'])


idx = pd.Index(np.arange(0,5000),name='frames')
df=pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=arrays)
```

Looks like this:

```
worms   worm1   worm2   worm3
bodyparts   head    vulva   tail    head    vulva   tail    head    vulva   tail
coords  x   y   x   y   x   y   x   y   x   y   x   y   x   y   x   y   x   y
frames                                                                      
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Now if I do:

```
df.columns.levels[1]
```

I get:

```
Index(['head', 'tail', 'vulva'], dtype='object', name='bodyparts')
```

**What I want:**

```
Index(['head', 'vulva', 'tail'], dtype='object', name='bodyparts')
```

Are there any options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you them in order of appearance:

```
pd.unique(df.columns.to_frame()['bodyparts'])
```

Outputs: `['head' 'vulva' 'tail']`